# The peculiar behavior of select box (Need your views)

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, web

One day i was just playing around with the select box and i came to a situation where the browser window was smaller than the select box's width and when you open the dropdown the select box options just moves right out of the whole browser window to let you see the options.

**P.S.**: You need to re-size the browser in order to see what i am talking about.

The [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kushal812/zkzrhoff/2/) to check it out : https://fiddle.jshell.net/kushal812/zkzrhoff/2/

Also when you apply the width to the select box then the dropdown opens on the left to accommodate the text(This works only on chrome).

Just trying to share this and get some of your views on it.

I know that it might not be a bug on the part of the browser or have been implemented in this way purposefully.

Have tested it on desktop Chrome 42 and firefox 37

**Ok so my views**:

**1)** The browser should calculate the width of the dropdown before opening it and accordingly should open it on the left or right but i am guessing the default is to open it on right.

**2)** The browser should open the dropdown with the width of the selectbox and use ellipsis to take the care of the extra text and show the whole text on hover.

Hope to hear your views too!!

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no real answer to this as each browser can render the select field in different ways. Also add to this the mobile browsers.

Applying a width may cause problems in some browsers too (I'm thinking IE from memory).

In my experience its best to leave the select fields pretty much as is but you can use 3rd party libraries to help make them more consistent from browser to browser i.e. https://select2.github.io/ However, this might not be the best option if you want the native look and feel on mobile etc.